# Expectation Operator

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

I use the following command to typeset `E[A|B]`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclareMathOperator{\ExpOp}{E}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\ExpArg}[1]{[}{]}{#1}
\newcommand{\Exp}{\ExpOp\ExpArg*}

\begin{document}
% usage:
$\Exp{A \mid B}$
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to define `\Exp` to accept an optional size parameter like `\bigg` for the brackets?

Comment: `\mid` is not a good symbol, 2 min and I'll post what I recommend to our users. BTW: always post full minimal examples.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since `\mid` does not make much sense then you read `\Exp{A \mid B}` (and cannot be scaled), I suggest hiding the `|` inside a specially crafted macro giving us a macro that support conditionals including scaling.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
% requires 2014 edition of mathtools
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathtools,bm,etoolbox}

\providecommand\given{}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP\Aver[1]{\mathbb{E}}{[}{]}{}{
\renewcommand\given{  \nonscript\:
  \delimsize\vert
  \nonscript\:
  \mathopen{}
  \allowbreak}
#1
}


\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \Aver{A} 
  \\
  \Aver{A \given B }
  \\
  \Aver*{\frac{A^2}{B^2+1}}
  \\
  \Aver[\bigg]{\frac{A^2}{B^2+1} \given c }
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

---

Addition, if you do not have the 2014 version of mathtools, you can use this

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\AverX[1]{[}{]}{
\renewcommand\given{  \nonscript\:
  \delimsize\vert
  \nonscript\:
  \mathopen{}
  \allowbreak}
#1
}

\newcommand\Exp{\mathbb{E}\AverX}
```

I'd might even consider using `\operatorname{\mathbb{E}}`

As far as I understand `\nonscript\:` makes `\:` disappear in a script context.
Since `\vert` is a *symbol* not a *fence*, `\vert - B` does not give the minus *sign* but rather an *addition* minus (wrong spacing). `\mathopen` makes a potential `-` behave as a sign rather than an addition. `\allowbreak` just allows line breaks after `\given`. Remove if not relevant (ie all conditionals are short).

[image]

Comment: Could you explain why `\nonscript`, `\mathopen` and `\allowbreak` (and what are they supposed to do). Nice answer, by the way.

Comment: @Manuel, see update

Comment: Thank you! I suppose you use more operators like this. If you ever publish these please let me know.

Comment: @ManuelSchmidt, lots, it is also useful for a probability operator (it is obvious from the code how to do that) and a `\Set` macro that use the same syntax `\Set{ x\in A \given x > 0}`

Comment: Regarding the second part of the answer (if you do not have the 2014 version of `mathtools`), where exactly would you place that snippet? (preamble? inside the document body? i.e. before or after `\begin{document}`?) Sorry, just run into this solution and am trying to familiarize myself with these types of declarations.

Comment: @Josh, always add macro definitions to your preamble.

Comment: Is it possible to easily change the surrounding symbols if I have nested expectations? I.e., make `\Aver{\Aver{x \given y}}` write `E[E{x | y}]`.
(I know I can define a new `\AverBracket`, but that seems like overkill)

Comment: @Robert with extra programming yes, but not using this construction. But isn't this a violation of the syntax? The []'s seems to be a part of the syntax.

Comment: If by syntax you mean what should appear in the final document, I think it makes sense to have a standard set of brackets when they occur alone (i.e., with no other delimiter as the closest character).
But if there are multiple delimiters next to each other I think it is more readable if they are not all the same.

Comment: There are different options on that. The way declare paired is made does not allow you to change the fences after the macro is made. You will have to make the macro from the ground up.